# Aggregate initialization vs uniform initialization

Tags: c++

The more I read about C++11 uniform initialization, the more confused I am. 
Scott Meyers in Effective Modern C++ (page 55) says that the statement

```
Widget w2{};
```

always calls the default constructor (even in the presence of constructor with a `std::initializer_list` argument).

At first sight, this seems to be consistent with the 4th edition of Stroustrup book "C++ programing language", e.g. according to the table on page 1200 the statement

```
std::atomic<T> x;
```

leaves the atomic variable uninitialized, while

```
std::atomic<T> x {};
```

calls "default constructor" so that x represents a value initialized T object.

However, I can't believe that `std::atomic<T> x;` does not call the default constructor in C++11 anymore, so I'm totally confused here.

Finally, after taking a look at C++11 standard (n3337 draft) my confusion is even bigger.
On page 1102 we have:

```
template <> struct atomic<integral > {
  //[...] list of non-constructor functions
  atomic() noexcept = default;
  constexpr atomic(integral ) noexcept;
  atomic(const atomic&) = delete;
  //[...] other non-constructor functions
};
```

While on page 1104 (point 29.5.5) we see

> The atomic integral specializations and the specialization
>   atomic shall have standard layout. They shall each have a
>   trivial default constructor and a trivial destructor. They shall each
>   support aggregate initialization syntax.

So classes with user defined constructor now support aggregate initialization?
Is this so because the constuctor is `constexpr`?

And what happens when we write

```
std::atomic<T> x {};
```

Is this the aggregate initialization? Or a call to the (trivial) default constructor?

Comment: don't read the drafts and draw conclusions from there, after reading the standard... the drafts were written before other stuff was standardized so they would have confusing things in them, some of the drafts depended on others being implemented first but most were written without knowledge or dependencies on other proposals...

Comment: This version of the draft is (allegedly) almost identical to the official C++11 standard.

Answer (score 5):

> So classes with user defined constructor now support aggregate initialization?

Only aggregates support aggregate initialization. An aggregate can have a user defined constructor only if the constructor is defined as defaulted or deleted.

This will change in C++20 where no user declared constructors are allowed at all.

> Is this so because the constuctor is consexpr?

`constexpr` has no effect on this.

> ```
> std::atomic<T> x {};
> ```
>
> Is this the aggregate initialization?

This is list initialization. If the type is an aggregate, then list initialization would aggregate initialize the object. `std::atomic` is not an aggregate, because it has a user-provided constructor that is neither defaulted nor deleted:

> ```
> constexpr atomic( T desired ) noexcept; // (2) (since C++11)
> ```

For `std::atomic`, this rule of list initialization applies:

> - Otherwise, if the initializer list has no elements and T is a class type with a default constructor, the object is **value-initialized**.

And value initialization invokes the default constructor for such class.